# Programmatically Get BIOS Boot Menu Key

Tags: c#, windows, bios

How can I programmatically get through whatever means what the BIOS boot menu key (e.g. F11) is on a particular computer. Say, that I have a WinForms application, which a technician can run, even in Administrative mode, and that would return the BIOS boot menu hot key.

One thought that I had was to use WMI and enumerate the `Win32_BIOS` key, such as the code below, but this information does not return the BIOS boot menu hotkey, at least not directly.

Here is the C# code snippet.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnumBios();
}

private void EnumBios()
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS";
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher wmiBiosItems = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
        {
            string textProperties = string.Empty;
            foreach (ManagementObject wmiBiosItem in wmiBiosItems.Get())
            {
                textProperties += $"BIOS Information{Environment.NewLine}";
                foreach (PropertyData item in wmiBiosItem.Properties)
                {
                    textProperties += $"\t{item.Name}";
                    if (null != item.Value)
                        textProperties += $" = {item.Value.ToString()}";
                    textProperties += $"{Environment.NewLine}";
                }
            }

            // Display the information.
            this.TxtOutput.Text = textProperties;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.TxtOutput.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
BIOS Information
    BiosCharacteristics = System.UInt16[]
    BIOSVersion = System.String[]
    BuildNumber
    Caption = BIOS Date: 02/16/16 09:38:11 Ver: V1.13B0
    CodeSet
    CurrentLanguage = en|US|iso8859-1
    Description = BIOS Date: 02/16/16 09:38:11 Ver: V1.13B0
    EmbeddedControllerMajorVersion = 255
    EmbeddedControllerMinorVersion = 255
    IdentificationCode
    InstallableLanguages = 1
    InstallDate
    LanguageEdition
    ListOfLanguages = System.String[]
    Manufacturer = American Megatrends Inc.
    Name = BIOS Date: 02/16/16 09:38:11 Ver: V1.13B0
    OtherTargetOS
    PrimaryBIOS = True
    ReleaseDate = 20160216000000.000000+000
    SerialNumber = To be filled by O.E.M.
    SMBIOSBIOSVersion = V1.13
    SMBIOSMajorVersion = 2
    SMBIOSMinorVersion = 8
    SMBIOSPresent = True
    SoftwareElementID = BIOS Date: 02/16/16 09:38:11 Ver: V1.13B0
    SoftwareElementState = 3
    Status = OK
    SystemBiosMajorVersion = 4
    SystemBiosMinorVersion = 6
    TargetOperatingSystem = 0
    Version = ALASKA - 1072009
```

I do not think WMI will be helpful, though might. How can I programmatically determine the BIOS, either UEFI or legacy does not apply for displaying the boot menu, boot menu key?

Comment: I don't think Windows allows access to such hardware information. at least not with c#, Such information can only be accessed from lower level languages like assembly or maybe c

Comment: I doubt if this is possible in general. The BIOS Hotkey menu isn't a standard, it is part of the BIOS and could be anywhere in the code. You could try searching for readable (English?) strings in the BIOS and filtering for hotkey terms, but that would be error prone at best.

Comment: @preciousbetine I am open to C or any language. Calling C/C++ is an exercise in Pinvoke. Even writing a driver would be an annoyance, but okay. I just do no know the methodology. The language stuff is relatively easy. What NetMage said is what I fear, no way to do it.

Comment: Even if WMI had a entry for it you could not trust it. Look at your own example output, it has entries the OEM failed to fill correctly. You see this all the time in SMBIOS data.